# Issue with Multiple 1 to 1 association through code first?

Tags: c#, sql, code-first

I am using Code First approach for creating Database. Here i am trying to implement 1 to 1 relationship with using `Shared primary key` approach:

```
public partial class AccountHolder
{
    public int AccountHolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonalDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

//Added later 
public partial class Nominee
{
    public int NomineeId { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonalDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonalDetail
{
    public int PersonalDetailId { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

My fluent Api code :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AccountHolder>().HasOptional(p => p.Detail)
                                            .WithRequired()
                                            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
        //Added later
        modelBuilder.Entity<Nominee>().HasOptional(p => p.Detail)
                                      .WithRequired()
                                      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Initially i had only 2 tables `AccountHolder` and `PersonalDetails` and the shared primary key approach was working fine on it. But now the issue occur when i added the `Nominee` table which also has 1 to 1 relationship with `PersonalDetails` . After adding new table `Nominee` when i run *Update-Database command* of *code first migration* than exception occure :

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_PersonalDetailId' already exists on table 'PersonalDetails'

Can anybody please tell me whats the problem and how can i solve this issue ?

**Edit :**

Here i am sharing my research over this issue, *please correct me if i am wrong*. May be this exception occur because in shared primary key approach the PK of dependent table is also a FK for the principal table. So in this case there are 2 principal table i.e `AccountHolder` and `Nominee` for 1 dependent table i.e. `PersonalDetail`. So when Entity framework try to create 2 FKs of the same name than the above mentioned exception will be the result.

Comment: You must use a base class (`AccountHolder` and `Nominee` deriving from it) with the  `PersonalDetail` property. I think this can work with TPH inheritance.

Comment: What's your migration look like?

Comment: I just read your edit, and yes.  PersonalDetail should be the principal table and AccountHolder and Nominee should be the dependent tables

Comment: But is there any why to resolve current conflict between 2 same name FKs in PersonalDetail ( 1 for AccountHolder and 1 for Nominee ) ?

Comment: Even if you resolve the naming issue, you cannot have one column be a foreign key to two tables.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand on my comment.

> Even if you resolve the naming issue, you cannot have one column be a foreign key to two tables.

Let's say your AccountHolder table has the following records

```
Id
----
1
2
3
```

And your Nominee table has the following records

```
Id
----
3
4
5
```

Let's say you want to insert a record into PersonalDetail with `DetailId = 3`.  Does that match Nominee 3 or AccountHolder 3?

Additionally, if you try to insert PersonalDetail with `DetailId = 2`,  you will get a FK violation because there is no Nominee 2.  The same applies if you want to insert `DetailId = 4`, there is no AccountHolder 4, so you will get a FK violation.

Comment: thanks for explanation, now its clear to me what i was doing wrong in this

Comment: note that simply switching the relationship around and making PersonalDetail the principal table will solve this problem.

Comment: If i understand your comment correctly than `principal can always exist without dependent` so i think only personalDetail without its owner (AccountHolder Or Nominee) doesn't make  sense, isn't ?

Comment: From a database perspective, that is true.  However, you can control that through business logic, so I probably wouldn't worry about it too much.